# Direct2D Bitmap Mask with opacity

Tags: winapi, hlsl, direct2d

The idea is to use the Direct2D Layers with a bitmap mask to mask-off an area with transparency when applying an effect. For that I use PushLayer with a bitmap mask like that in a device context:

```
            m_d2dContext->PushLayer(D2D1::LayerParameters1(D2D1::InfiniteRect(), 0, D2D1_ANTIALIAS_MODE_PER_PRIMITIVE, D2D1::IdentityMatrix(), 1.0f, br, D2D1_LAYER_OPTIONS1_NONE), nullptr);
```

Where 'br' is the bitmap mask. This works fine when the effect is, for example, a rainbow:

Original image:

[image]

Full effect:

[image]

Masked effect:

[image]

The problem starts when I want to make the pixels outside the mask  transparent (and not a black background).

For example, in this simple HLSL effect:

```
float4 mainImage(in float2 fragCoord, float2 MV2)
{
    return float4(0,0,0,0);
}
```

All pixels are returned transparent when no mask is applied (correct). When the same as above mask is applied however, even the pixels outside the mask are colored as the original image.

If I return a hard black color:

```
float4 mainImage(in float2 fragCoord, float2 MV2)
{
    return float4(0,0,0,1);
}
```

Then the result is correct:

[image]

But this black is black, not transparent. My current workaround is to apply a Chroma Key to this final effect to replace the black pixels with transparent pixels.

Why wouldn't the mask work with "transparent" pixels?

The same happens when I use a "Flood Fill" effect. When the color of the flood fill is opaque, mask works correctly. When it's transparent, masking it simply ignores it.

Alpha 0xFF:

[image]

Alpha 0x00:

[image]

Note that geometric masks work correctly.

Comment: Not sure I fully understand what you're trying to do and the problem you have w/o some reproducing sample but have you checked at features of D2D1_LAYER_OPTIONS1 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/Direct2D/direct2d-layers-overview#d2d1_layer_parameters1-and-d2d1_layer_options1

Comment: @SimonMourier, yes, no change in output. I dont' understand when, there are opaque pixels, the PushLayer stuff successfully masks them but when there are transparent pixels it doesn't.

Comment: Did you try [Pixel adjustments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct2d/effects-overview#pixel-adjustments)? `opacityBrush` [is used to modify the opacity of the layer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/d2d1/ns-d2d1-d2d1_layer_parameters#members).

Comment: @YangXiaoPo-MSFT I can adjust the pixel directly in HLSL. The problem is that the direct2d layer mechanism does not mask transparent pixels.

Comment: Is there a sample I can use to reproduce? You can open an incident at https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/support/?tabs=Contact-us.